# How to make two buttons have exactly the same height and width Using Dialog Editor in VC++?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, button, dialog

It seems that we can only align buttons, using `Align Lefts` and `Align Tops` menu items after right-clicking selected buttons.

I know that copying a existing button would produce a new one with exactly the same size. However, sometimes I need to make two or more existing buttons in the Dialog Editor have the same size.

Answer (score 0):

Find the button width and button height properties in the properties window and set them to the values that you want.

Comment: Thanks. But it seems that the width and height of a button are not showed in its properties window. I'm using VS 2010, Win32.

Comment: Try giving the button a name, e.g. Button1. And inside your C++ code, set Button1.width = <some value> and Button1.height = <some value>. I'm not sure, why is it not shown in your properties windows. I'm using VS2013.